# Can I recover an Outlook meeting invite that auto deleted when accepted?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

I use Outlook 2013 at work. When accepting any invites to a meeting, the invite deletes itself as the meeting goes into my calendar.
I've found I can disable this in Options and have done so.
However, I accepted a meeting earlier that had some notes in the body of the invite. 
Does anyone know I way I can recover this as it told me what to bring along and I cannot remember!

I would be most grateful!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Exchange Calendar invites when accepted go to the Deleted folder.

Comment: You can find the meeting meeting invitation in your Deleted Items folder.